# How to Make a Call directly in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I know it was very simple to do it but I come across a very strange issue. I have to call  Police in danger Situation by just tapping a button. So I have used following code to call.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:100"));
            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            ctx.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Added `CALL_PHONE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`. The Issue is that it is opening the 100 on Dial Pad but not making call directly. I want that to happen immediately when user clicks on the button.

When I tried to to put +91 before 100 it is calling the number automatically but why plus is required for such numbers. So Someone help me how to solve this issue

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with '100' not being a valid phone number on the US phone system. (This is probably a bug)

Comment: Hi,Have you found any solution for this?. Still its happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of `ACTION_CALL`:

> Note: there will be restrictions on which applications can initiate a call; most applications should use the ACTION_DIAL.
>
> Note: this Intent cannot be used to call emergency numbers. Applications can dial emergency numbers using ACTION_DIAL, however.

So it seems this behavior is on purpose.

Comment: Specifically, you need the `CALL_PRIVILEGED` permission, which is not available to ordinary SDK applications.

Answer (score 1):

There are two intents to call/start calling: ACTION_CALL and ACTION_DIAL.
ACTION_DIAL will only open the dialer with the number filled in, but allows the user to actually call or reject the call. ACTION_CALL will immediately call the number and requires an extra permission.
So make sure you have the permission

Comment: did you got my question first @user69226. I know that ACTION_CALL will directly call the mobile numbers but that will not call emergency numbers like 100 etc.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem that the android system doesnt recognize `100` as a valid phone number, instead if you put the country code before it then it works fine. TO solve such issue take a look at this library [libnhonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/). You could use it something like this

```
public static ArrayList<String> extractPhoneNumber(String content) {

    ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>(0);

    PhoneNumberUtil instance = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

    //Change IT with your contry code
    Iterable<PhoneNumberMatch> matches = instance.findNumbers(content, "IT");

    Iterator<PhoneNumberMatch> iterator = matches.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        numbers.add(instance.format(iterator.next().number(), PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL));
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void phoneCall()
{
 String phoneCallUri = "tel:91";
 Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
 startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to directly call without user intervention..

```
String uri = "tel:" + num.trim();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Long time passed. But may help someone else.
If you want to call directly, you should use [requestPermissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) method.

**1.** Add this line to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

**2.** Define a class variable in the activity class:

```
private static Intent phoneCallIntent; //If use don't need a member variable is good to use a static variable for memory performance.
```

**3.** Add these lines to the **onCreate** method of the activity:

```
final String permissionToCall = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;
//Assume that you have a phone icon.
(findViewById(R.id.menuBarPhone)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view) {
        phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.callNumber))); //Uri.parse("tel:your number")
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainFrame.this, permissionToCall) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainFrame.this, new String[]{permissionToCall}, 1);
            return;
        }
        startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
    }
});
```

**4.** And for making a call immediately after clicking on **Allow button**, override [onRequestPermissionsResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == 1){
        final int permissionsLength = permissions.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < permissionsLength; i++) {
            if(grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

When a user give the permission, next time there will be no dialogue box and call will be make directly.