# Action_Call intent doesnt start call directly when dialing #190

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I'm trying to call two different numbers, for #193 it works correctly, by that I mean pressing the button start calling the number:

```
btnb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.activity_home_button_b);

btnb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:193"));
startActivity(callIntent);

}
});
```

But for the #190 it does give me the screen to dial the number instead of making the call.

```
btna = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.activity_home_button_a);
btna.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:190"));
startActivity(callIntent);
}
});
```

Any advice?

Comment: could you add your buttons code as well?

Comment: does it show any message on logcat?

Comment: I had a second look in the logcat and I did find this:
 
Cannot call potential emergency number '190' with CALL Intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster }.

Comment: So there's your answer hehe :)

Comment: Is there any way to avoid that? I'm doing an emergency call app!

Comment: I did find another answer on the subject:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238410/how-to-make-a-call-directly-in-android

Comment: @giacomoni Would you post a answer as you did help me to find it?

Comment: Well, i use the same code as you to make call in my app, and searching for it on google i have not found any workarounds for that. Like @Henry said on the answer you posted, you can't use that on emergency numbers.