# How to get notified when incoming phone call arrive in Qt for Android

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4, qtandroidextras

I am using Qt 5.10 for Android. My program is based on Qt Widgets and it is written in C++. I need to get notified when someone is calling. Is there a way in Qt to know messages such as incoming phone call (Maybe this can be extended to Qt mobile framework)?

If possible, please share code for reference, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I know Qt does not support your need directly. I recommend you to dive into androidextras and JNI class. With using intents you should able to solve your problem. There is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317048/how-to-make-a-call-with-qt-directly-from-the-application) to call someone with using Intent Class and you also can parse incoming call from Intents.