# Is there any way to call a number without pressing green button in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

hello i m new in flutter i m developing an application in flutter in which there is button after click on the button it will call directly to the number without pressing green button how i can archive this functionality.
i have used URL launcher but it is opening the diler and we need to press green button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Make a Call directly in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238410/how-to-make-a-call-directly-in-android)

Comment: no my app is in flutter it is not a native android app

Comment: I know, if something cannot be made in native languages. cross-platform language like flutter can't do it too.

Comment: (i got the sol) _launchURL() async {
    // Replace 12345678 with your tel. no.

    android_intent.Intent()
      ..setAction(android_action.Action.ACTION_CALL)
      ..setData(Uri(scheme: "tel", path: "your number"))
      ..startActivity().catchError((e) => print(e));

  }

Comment: good for you. did it work?

Comment: yes it is thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

i got the solution for android
we can use call_flutter plugin for the same